CSS to "scale" Image to Fit Browser Window height and width
I am generating a static site where the images and set within a responsive "picture frame" so the Mat is the same size on each side, regardless of the image's aspect ratio.  This is working well; however...
I want to ensure that the whole "picture frame" is visible in the browser window. Currently, the frame is sized to the width, meaning tall images scroll off the bottom.
Can someone look at my code and suggest how I dynamically resize the "picture frame" so it is 100% visible in the browser window?
There is a JSFiddle here - link


.frame {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 7px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.mat {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
}

.art {
    position: absolute;
}

.art img {
    width: 100%;
}

.art:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
}
<div class="frame" style="padding-bottom: 115.09%">
  <div class="mat" style="top: 2.1721%; bottom: 2.1721%; left: 2.50%; right: 2.50%;">
    <div class="art" style="top: 11.354%; bottom: 11.354%; left: 13.158%; right: 13.158%;">
      <img src="https://cw109eu.uk/images/portfolios/recent/231106-44511-1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Thanks

Make the image the same size as its container (using grid layout is probably better than absolute positioning). You also don't need that much nesting, just a border and a padding on the image.
Here's a working snippet producing the result you want.


html, body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 100%/ 100%
}

html { height: 100% }

img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 2vmin #000;
    padding: 13vmin;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    box-shadow: 
        0 10px 7px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 
        0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0 , .5) inset
}
<img src='https://cw109eu.uk/images/portfolios/recent/231106-44511-1.jpg'>



EDIT: Just in case I misunderstood and what you actually want is this:


html, body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 100%/ 100%
}

html { height: 100% }

img {
    place-self: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 2vmin #000;
    padding: 8vmin;
    max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 
        0 10px 7px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 
        0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0 , .5) inset
}
<img src='https://cw109eu.uk/images/portfolios/recent/231106-44511-1.jpg'>




This is looking very good - much cleaner than the code I was using. But....
Adding the html and body styles is breaking my site.  Anyway of getting this to work just targeting the specific page?
Still learning :-)

@philC In my case, the body is the image container. You need to add the grid-related body styles on whatever image container you have.

My lack of knowledge is failing me here.  I have tried to add the body styles to a container for the image, but it is failing to resize.  Can you look at my updated Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Phil89a/wg9ce8ft/14/) and tell me what I am doing wrong ?

@PhilC One, you have another div in between and two, the height of the container needs to be based on something other than the image. In my demos, there's no other element in between the body and the img and the height of the body is computed from that of its html parent, whose height in turn depends on the background.

okay got that and I now have that part working :-).     Next question is I need to add a second frame (to make the image look like it is sitting behind the mat).  How do I using the code at https://jsfiddle.net/Phil89a/wg9ce8ft/37/ include the CSS .art-frame after .frame is applied ?
Nearly there :-)
